# datastax backup service not working

Tags: backup, datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

we're using datastax DSE 4.6.1 with `opscenter 5.1.0` on EC2 (4 nodes running on m2.4xlarge)

we setup the new backupservice, and it worked, but now i get an error:

> "Snapshot of all keyspaces on node xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx failed:
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassFormatError:
>   Invalid method Code length 116786 in class file clojure/core$eval73,
>   compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0) (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)"

any ideas? it won't work neither on local backups nor on S3.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (OPSC-4587) that will be fixed in OpsCenter 5.1.1 and should be out very soon.  Unfortunately in the meantime there is no workaround other than downgrading to OpsCenter 5.0.2

**Update:** 5.1.1 just dropped and includes the fix! [Release Notes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/release_notes/opscReleaseNotes511.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Is there a guide to downgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Try just one keyspace at a time. This is a known issue and we expect there to be a fix in the next minor release.

[Fixed in 5.1.1](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/release_notes/opscReleaseNotes511.html)

Comment: tried that already...only trying to backup my keyspace...still failing:
2015-02-25 17:29:07+0000 [dse02] ERROR: Agent for 10.159.16.71 was unable to complete operation (http://10.159.16.71:61621/ops/take-snapshot?req-id=f4ea3617-650a-4655-b7b9-4011c258c593): clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 88763 in class file clojure/core$eval141, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)
 same error

Comment: Do you have a lot of tables / columns in the keyspace

Comment: Other smaller ks work? I'll post here as soon as the fix is GA

Comment: when i ran a backup of the keyspaces dse_system, Opscenter and system_traces it works (they are really small, it fails with the system Keyspace "javax.management.RuntimeErrorException: FSWriteError in /raid0/cassandra/data/system/NodeIdInfo/snapshots/opscenter_adhoc_2015-02-26-13-07-54-UTC" and with my own keyspace with the error i stated before

Comment: no update on this? we cannot use any kind of backups, thinking of downgrading opscenter to use the old backup system

Comment: The engineering team at datastax is working hard to get a release out that will contain this fix. I don't have a hard date but we expect it to be soon. I will continue to update here. Apologize for this inconvenience.